# VBA | Using defined name with formula

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA.

I am trying to use the value of a defined name in a function.
The code I have below does not throw an error, but it shows that my variable does not contain a value, but an expression, as shown in the image.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim segunda As String
   segunda = ActiveWorkbook.Names("Week5_FirstDay").RefersTo
   MsgBox segunda
End Sub
```

[image]

I tried to define segunda as a range object, which ended up throwing the error below. I think that makes sense, considering how Week5_FirstDay is defined.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim segunda As Range
   segunda = ActiveWorkbook.Names("Week5_FirstDay").RefersToRange
   MsgBox segunda.Value
End Sub
```

[image]

I also tried to use the Evaluate function, with no success.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim segunda As String
   segunda = ActiveWorkbook.Names("Week5_FirstDay").RefersTo
   MsgBox Evaluate(segunda)
End Sub
```

[image]

I also read about the Eval method, but excel does not recognize it.

This is how the names are defined in my workbook.
[image: ![enter image description here]

Here's how the name Week1_FirstDay is calculated:

```
DATE(ano;MONTH(DATEVALUE(mes&"1"));8-WEEKDAY(DATE(ano;MONTH(DATEVALUE(mes&"1"));1);12))
```

Ano and Mes correspond to an year and month defined in two cells.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Try `Set segunda = ActiveWorkbook.Names("Week5_FirstDay").RefersToRange`

Comment: Is `ActiveWorkbook.Names("Week5_FirstDay").RefersToRange` just a cell or more than that? I think that could be the reason you are getting the error

Comment: @FunThomas I tried it, forgot to put it on post. It throws the same error

Comment: @shahkalpesh it is a date that is calculated based on another defined name (also a date).

Comment: Sorry, I dont have excel handy. Does `Evauate("Week5_FirstDay")` help?

Comment: @shahkalpesh I tried to do  segunda = Evaluate("Week5_FirstDay") with segunda as a string but I got a type mismatch error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `RefersTo` returns a string, `Evaluate` works well with it
- `RefersToRange` return a range object if it is avaiable. It raises error 1004 if you try to use `ActiveWorkbook.Names("Week5_FirstDay").RefersToRange` because it is a formula instead of a range.

```
Option Explicit

Sub demo()
    Dim segunda As String
    Dim rngseg As Range
    segunda = ActiveWorkbook.Names("Week5_FirstDay").RefersTo
    Debug.Print segunda
    Debug.Print Format(Application.Evaluate(segunda), "yyyy/mm/dd")
    Set rngseg = ActiveWorkbook.Names("Week4_FirstDay").RefersToRange
    Debug.Print rngseg.Address
End Sub
```

Output

```
=Week4_FirstDay+7
2023/11/11
$A$1
```

[image]

---

> Reproduce OP's formula and defined name, `Evaluate` works well

[image]

Comment: When I try to use the evaluate method that way it throws a Type mismatch error. The way the names are defined is similar to what you did.

Comment: Please test my code. What's the first ouput in Immediate window before `Type mismatch error`? I guess `similar` means different. Please show the difference in OP.

Comment: I tested your code and it printed =Week4_FirstDay+7. It throw the Type Mismatch error on the second print. I added a print of the defined names at the end of my post.

Comment: What's the `scope` of names? Please update screenshot to include the scope column. Apply a formula `=Week1_FirstDay` on any cell, do you get the correct value?

Comment: I edited the print. The scope is the workbook. I can use tha formula on every worksheet.

Comment: `Debug.Print Format(Application.Evaluate("Week1_FirstDay"), "yyyy/mm/dd")` Does it work well?

Comment: It also throws a Type mismatch error.

Comment: I would suggest that create a new workbook as my screenshot and test `Evaluate`. If it works well, it means your workbook might be broken.

Comment: I created a new workbook as you said and it worked. Any idea about what's going on in the other one?

Comment: The best way is to re-bulid it from scratch. I knew it sounds crazy. If I were you, I am going to backup and delete all `defined names` then re-create them. All can be done with VBA code. I can't gurantee it will fix the issue.

Comment: I tried to use a previous version of my workbook without any vba code. I deleted these defined names and created just the first one (Week1_FirstDay). Then I tried your code with this name. It throws the same error on the line with the Evaluate method. Do you think it might be because of the formula I use on this name?

Comment: I also tried to define names as in your example in the original workbook and it works fine. Do you have any idea why I have an error with the original defined names?

Comment: Pleases post the formula of Week1_FirstDay as text in OP. We can test it. It would be helpful to clarify what's ano and mes.

Comment: I edited my post with the formula and the meaning of ano and mes.

Comment: I have tested it w/o any issue. Please review the screenshot in my response.

Comment: Could be not working because you have `;` as field separator. Evaluate needs `,`.

Comment: Some non-English version Excel uses `;` as the separator in formula. But I'm not sure if `Evaluate` is compatible with it or not.

Comment: I tried to use , instead of ; but excel just shows a window saying that there's a problem with my formula

Comment: @taller Thank you so much for helping me with this problem. I just found out why it was still throwing an error. The month name was not written in English and, although it worked fine calculating the values for the defined names, it was not working in the Evaluate VBA method. I changed it to English and it's working.